# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::scoped()

Tags: php, laravel, paystack

I am developing a Laravel application which requires paystack for payment processig. When I tried to install spatie/laravel-webhook-client through composer, using `composer require spatie/laravel-webhook-client` I got the following error:

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
>
> Error
>
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::scoped()
>
> at
> C:\wamp64-new\www\vendor\spatie\laravel-webhook-client\src\WebhookClientServiceProvider.php:30
> 26▕         }
> 27▕
> 28▕         Route::macro('webhooks', fn (string $url, string $name = 'default') => Route::post($url,
> '\Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookController')->name("webhook-client-{$name}"));
> 29▕   ➜  30▕         $this->app->scoped(WebhookConfigRepository::class, function () {
> 31▕             $configRepository = new WebhookConfigRepository();
> 32▕
> 33▕             collect(config('webhook-client.configs'))
> 34▕                 ->map(fn (array $config) => new WebhookConfig($config))
>
> 1
> C:\wamp64-new\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
> Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookClientServiceProvider::boot()
>
> 2
> C:\wamp64-new\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the
> post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: what version of Laravel are you running? `php artisan --version`